# My PHP code is just a comment in my HTML content

Tags: php, javascript, html, comments

I have a basic HTML page with some JavaScript code on it, and when I try to put any PHP code in the body, it reads it as a comment.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("table")
                .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
                .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Demo</h1>

            <!-- PHP code in here -->

            <?php
                echo "test php";
            ?>

            <!--
                ...
                Main code for a table here
            -->
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using a server to deliver this, correct?

Comment: do you mean it prints as plane text? if so make sure PHP is running on your server and hooked in properly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you either don't have PHP installed or you're not using a file extension which invokes the PHP engine - is your file called `Blah.php`?

Some things to check:

- You're serving the file from a web server (not locally)
- The server has PHP installed
- PHP is configured to handle the file type you're using (usually *.php*)
- creating a new file with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and serving it should give you lots of information about your PHP install.
- If you have access to the server, you should be able to run PHP from the command line/shell

Comment: ...and are you actually running, and going through, a server? (An `http:` or `https:` protocol, **not** `file:`.)

Comment: ugh. hit me with a stick, it was html

Comment: @TJ - Good points, I'd edited to add the list by the time I saw your comment but +1 anyway :)

Comment: @Glen - when someone answers your question, hit the checkmark next to their answer so they get credit and everyone knows the problem is solved.

Comment: @UltimateBrent Thanks for the support and pointing that out but I believe we're still inside the minimum time a Q can be open before an answer is awarded. (At least we were when Glenn commented)

Comment: yup, they should kill that time limit, at least when you have great people around. (ps. i get tons of info from stackoverflow, first post, great stuff)