# PHP: Code gets turned into HTML <!-- Comments? -->

Tags: php, javascript, html

when I enter in code like this:

```
<p>Hello <? echo $name; ?>, How are you?</p>
```

It prints:

```
<p>Hello <!--? echo $name; ?-->, How are you?</p>
```

As a comment. I have it in a file called base.js with this code:

```
function showName() {
   document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<p>Hello <? echo $name; ?>, How are you?</p>";
}
```

So I embed the .js file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
```

So, after it changes the `<p id="name"></p>` I get:

```
<p id="name">Hello <!--? echo $name; ?-->, How are you?</p>
```

I had the code in the .php file, and it seemed to work fine. Now that I have it in a separate base.js file, it ceases to function. Help!

Comment: That is because it is no longer php.

Comment: You can not evaluate PHP code from Javascript! Ok if you tell the server to preprocess .js files as PHP you can get away with that; try calling the file .js.php

Comment: PHP has to be parsed before you output javascript. You probably need <?php or you need to change your webserver configuration. Putting PHP in a JS file won't work at all because the webserver won't know to parse it through PHP. PHP is server side. Javascript is client side.

Comment: apparently *.js files get not parsed by php on your server. you can in fact parse .js-files if you want: http://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/ But i would not recommend...

Comment: that's right. apache determines whether to interpret PHP-code in a file from the file name's extension, usually `*.php`. you can just rename the file `base.js.php` and include it the usual way. your browser won't mind. `<script type="text/javascript" src="base.js.php"></script>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because it is no longer php.

Change to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="base.php"></script>

and have a 
<?php header("content-type:text/javascript"); 
$name = "...";
?>

function showName() {
   document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<p>Hello <?php echo $name; ?>, How are you?</p>";
}
```

Or

change to

```
function showName(name) {
   document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<p>Hello "+name+", How are you?</p>";
}
```

and in the php file have

```
<script>
// using json_encode to make the string safe for script injection. 
// Still needs quotes for a single string
showName("<?php echo json_encode($name); ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: That last one should be `showName(<?php echo json_encode($name); ?>);` for safety reasons.

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is the most unconstructive action at SO

Comment: The <?php ?> tag worked fine for me. On OSX 10 with default Apache server, just followed the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997000/html-recognizes-my-php-code-as-comments

Answer (score 0):

PHP is processed on the server side, not client side. You cannot execute PHP code on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Thist of all you cannot run php in the JS.
The second is you have to do smth like this to avoid problem with comments:

```
//<![CDATA[
    function showName() {
       document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<p>Hello <? echo $name; ?>, How are you?</p>";
    }
//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

speaking from 2021 :

**1-** you can use **js** and **php**.

**2-** **CDATA** is deprecated.