# My php code gets commented out by the browser

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Code gets turned into HTML <!— Comments? -->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368841/php-code-gets-turned-into-html-comments)

I have some very, very simple php code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Something</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Something</h2>


        <?php
            $val = $_POST['a'];
            echo 'Value: ' . $val . '<br />;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I press the submit button in an form I've made, the browser comments out the php code like this:

```
<!--?php
     //the stuff i do above
?-->
```

Anyone knows what this is?

Comment: The server isn't configured to interpret PHP files. Review your server configuration.

Comment: Could be as simple as you're server isn't configured to look for PHP in your ".html" files? Change the extension to ".php", and try to navigate to the page.

Comment: It's not duplicate, in that question the code was inside JavaScript

Comment: I have the exact same problem on a server that already hosts php sites

Comment: StackOverflow won't let me answer this question, and yes, I have the same question you have. In your case, when I tried to execute your code on WampServer, it told me that the index `a` is undefined. (This may or may not resolve your question.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you using CMS?
This looks like Joomla behavour for PHP code when you just insert it in template without using special module.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side language. It is evaluated on the server, and the results of the evaluation replace the code itself.

This is by design and it would terrible if the PHP source code for every page were included in the HTML comments (eg you can see database passwords, etc.).

You cannot see PHP from the client (i.e. HTML source).

Comment: Yah, but browser willn't autocomment PHP code with <!-- - it will just shown as text.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368841/php-code-gets-turned-into-html-comments

Comment: As far as I see there is PHP inside JavaScript code in that question, not inside clear HTML. In HTML such code should be just shown as text, without adding <!-- comments markup.

Comment: @DaneSoul I'm pretty sure it is the browser doing the commenting out, not apache. I just saved a file test.html containing PHP code inside `<?php` tags to the public folder of my apache server and then visited the URL in my browser (Google Chrome 23.0.1271.97) and in a terminal (specifically, using Python's urllib2). Chrome commented out the PHP code. urllib2 gave me the file contents verbatim, without commenting anything out. Of course, this only confirms it for my particular apache setup and browser choice, so it's conceivable (but unlikely) that the mechanism was different in the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're missing a closing `'` at the end of your echo statement.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the actual problem in question.

Comment: but worthy of noting, nonetheless.

Comment: Both correct.  Sorry, I got in a hurry and didn't read the part with the example of <!--php-->